# How to create grouped bar chart for situations

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I am trying to create a grouped bar chart. In this chart, I want to compare whether they survived or died according to their embarkation points(C,Q,S). In this piece of code, i can't decide what y is going to be.

```
df_drop_Emb = df_titanic.dropna(subset= ["Embarked"])
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
sns.barplot(x="Embarked", 
            y="Survived",
            hue="Survived", 
            data=df_drop_Emb)
plt.ylabel("number of people", size=14)
plt.xlabel("ports", size=14)
plt.title(" the number of passengers who survived for each port", size=18)
```

[image: current output but wrong]

Comment: It's still better to use `pd.crosstab` as I demonstrated in the previous question. `.groupby` requires extra steps like `.reset_index`.  `pd.crosstab(df.embarked, df.survived).plot(kind='bar')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably need to groupby and count the lived/died in the survivors column first.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
df = df.groupby(['Embarked', 'Survived']).size().reset_index(name='count')
sns.barplot(data=df, x='Embarked',y='count',hue='Survived')
```

[image]

Comment: perfect solution. thank you